# matching negative number in a line not working

Tags: perl

How to match negative number in a line.

```
input line :strongest_signal_indication   Invalid {-1}  some text
```

I was trying this regex expression:

```
/ ( [+-]?\d+ )| (\s+ ( \{ [^-]+ \} |\S+)) /xg
```

but it did not work for me

Any help please

Comment: Do you need to simply pick up that number?  Are there other numbers on the line? To match a (possibly negative) integer in a string you only need `my ($num) = $str =~ /([+-]?\d+)/`, so please explain a little more

Comment: @zdim i need to pickup the only (-1) number in all occurrence in a file

Comment: OK.  Then what I wrote in the previous comment is all you need. It finds and captures a number and stores it in `$num`, given that `$str` contains a string.  It that string doesn't containt a number then `$num` winds up `undef`. For a whole file, you can read it line by line and use the above so that `$str` has a line as you go.  Which part of this is the problem?  Can you post the complete code you are trying?

Comment: @sam: I assure you that your comments are very much stranger than my own. I offered constructive criticism, and am astonished how sensitive you are to it. My knowledge in this field is that it is a bad idea to copy code blindly from the internet and plug it into your own program without spending the effort to understand what it does. It is a huge security risk, and you may suffer all kinds of side effects that you didn't intend or expect. I am sharing that knowledge with you as you described. This is especially odd coming from someone who has never had a positive vote for any of his questions.

Comment: @Borodin i had asked my doubt what its nor working for me but you are saying something different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern actually does match.

```
$ perl -E'
   say
      "Invalid {-1}" =~ / ( [+-]?\d+ )| (\s+ ( \{ [^-]+ \} |\S+)) /x
         ? "match" : "no match";'
match
```

In fact, `/ [+-]? \d+ /x` would have sufficed.